# Rcpp: dynamically update a list

Tags: r, rcpp

I am seeking solutions to dynamically updating a list.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List Test(){
List L;
List L1=List::create(12,45,22,44);
L=Language("c",L,L1).eval();//update, add L1's elements on L's back.
return L;
}
```

The above doesn't work since "List L;" makes L an empty list.

However, if I write an additional function:

```
List connectlist(List& a, List& b){
return Language("c",a,b).eval();
}
```

and replace "L=Language("c",L,L1).eval();" with "connectlist(L,L1);", it will work.

Can anyone tell me the reason? Or is there any simpler way to dynamically update a list in Rcpp?

PS: I made some time tests and they showed calling "c" function to combine 2 lists is faster than making a new list by copying elements from the 2 lists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Rcpp's `List::operator=` is broken. With this code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void Test(){
  List L;
  List L1=List::create(12,45,22,44);
  SEXP x=Language("c",L,L1).eval();//update, add L1's elements on L's back.
  Rprintf( "x = " ) ; Rf_PrintValue(x) ; Rprintf( "\n") ;

  L = x;
  Rprintf( "L = " ) ; Rf_PrintValue(L) ; Rprintf( "\n") ;

}
```

I get this with the current devel version of Rcpp.

```
> Test()
x = [[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 22

[[4]]
[1] 44


L = list()
```

which is wrong. However, I get something correct with Rcpp11:

```
> Test()
x = [[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 22

[[4]]
[1] 44


L = [[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 22

[[4]]
[1] 44
```

Comment: Thank you Romain! I'll look into C++11!

Comment: This is more related to better implementation of the Rcpp api rather than a C++98 / C++11 difference.

Comment: You just to be plain: you can of course use C++11 just fine with Rcpp, see e.g. [this](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/first-steps-with-C++11/) or [this](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simple-lambda-func-c++11/) article at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) -- both where written in early 2013.

Comment: Sure. Just as much as you can also not use Rcpp at all. That comment is pointless

Comment: Just keepin' the record straight.

Answer (score 3):

You are making the same mistake as in your last question.

C++ is C++. And R is R.  And they are different.

Just because you know a `c()` function / operator in R does not mean that this is how to do in C++.  You should probably read some C++ or programming texts -- there are equivalent data structures to grow object and to append.  Many of us like the STL for this, and Rcpp helps you get your R data to and from it easily.

*Edit on 2014-03-12*  Thanks to a commit by Kevin, this now also works in the release candidate Rcpp 0.11.1 which should hit CRAN in a few days (and which you can get from GitHub now).

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> packageDescription("Rcpp")$Version
[1] "0.11.1"                             # as on GitHub, to be on CRAN soon
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/listconcat.cpp")
R> Test()
x = [[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 22

[[4]]
[1] 44


L = [[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 22

[[4]]
[1] 44


R>
```

It is still the wrong programming idiom to concatenate two C++ lists via a call to R, but if
someone really insists on doing it, well now they can.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Sometimes I can't resist the charm of speed of loops and recursions in C++ so I directly translate all the R codes to C++ codes using the simplest way, while my mind is still like you said in the R bubble..By the way, thank you for making Rcpp.

Comment: There is indeed a lot of charm. But do C++ when in C++ -- use eg `std::list<...>` and then convert when you're done. Don't write R in C++, just write C++ and then return to R for R.

Comment: Hi Dirk, one more similar question if it is, suppose 2 NumericVectors x and y, when I do x[seq(0,3)]=y[seq(2,5)], x won't change, but if I do NumericVector temp=y[seq(2,5)]; x[seq(0,3)]=temp; it works. Is this the formal/best way to assign part of a vector with part of the responding vector?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel this is a bug. see my answer. This might not be the way to do it, but it sure should have worked.

Comment: @RomainFrancois  It may well be a bug on our end too but I care more about what is to me the wrong usage idiom.  We do say repeatedly that Rcpp objects, with the underlying SEXPs, cannot grow easily and cheaply (but force full copies). Insisting on it is already bad, forcing it via a call to R's `c()` function is doubly bad.

Comment: @user2961927: This bug has been taken care in the version of Rcpp which should hit CRAN within a few days.  Thanks for the report -- but please think about another way to combine lists. Maybe use `std::list` from the STL instead.

Comment: It seems (to me) lists are good to get more complex data from R to C and vice versa - but I found it difficult to, e.g., (recursively) manipulate Rcpp List entries within C (for which the STL may provide better solutions). It would have been good to highlight this latter limitation in some Rccp introductions though ...