# How to concatenate Lists in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to `c()` 2 lists in Rcpp, but I'm struggling to get the same structure as I would in R.

Here is some simple data + example:

```
rlist = list(a = "123")
listadd = list(typ = "fdb")
c(rlist, listadd)
```

which gives me this:

> ```
> $a
> [1] "123"
>
> $typ
> [1] "fdb"
> ```

---

With Rcpp I only found `push_back` to do more or less what I want but the structure is a bit different. I also tried to use `emplace_back` based on this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/emplace_back/) but it doesnt seem to be implemented in Rcpp.

```
cppFunction('
List cLists(List x, List y) {
  x.push_back(y);
  return(x);
}')
```

which gives me:

> ```
> cLists(rlist, listadd)
> $a
> [1] "123"
>
> [[2]]
> [[2]]$typ
> [1] "fdb"
> ```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22288025/3682794) I know that I could use  `Language("c",x,y).eval();` to use R's `c()` function and get the correct result, but that doesn't seem to be the right way.

*So I was wondering how can I concatenate lists in Rcpp correctly?*

EDIT:
Based on @Dirk's comment, I tried to create a new list and fill them with the other lists elements, but then I loose the element names.

```
cppFunction('
List cLists(List x, List y) {
  int nsize = x.size(); 
  int msize = y.size(); 
  List out(nsize + msize);

  for(int i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
    out[i] = x[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < msize; i++) {
    out[nsize+i] = y[i];
  }
  return(out);
}')
```

Output:

> ```
> cLists(rlist, listadd)
> [[1]]
> [1] "123"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "fdb"
> ```

Comment: That is really not at all how Rcpp works. You would be well advised to study a few existing examples, read some source code, look at the Rcpp Gallery, or ... even read my book.

Comment: I did, but I could not find an example which concatenates 2 lists. Therefore my question..

Comment: Create a new list object with n+m elements, fill in the n from list1 and then m from list2.  You are done writing the helper in half the time it takes to argue here.  Rcpp design is bound by R data structures underlying so you can't (or shouldn't) always pick STL idioms.  Ie we warn that `push_back()` is expensive as it implies _full copies each time_.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not that easy for me and definitly not faster. I included an attempt based on your comment, but like that I'm loosing the names.

Comment: Names are in another 'attributes' vector, you need to deal with that the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance hit for your implementation seems to come from copying the `name` attribute to stl string vectors.  You can avoid it like so:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)
cppFunction('
List cLists(List x, List y) {
  int nsize = x.size(); 
  int msize = y.size(); 
  List out(nsize + msize);

  CharacterVector xnames = x.names();
  CharacterVector ynames = y.names();
  CharacterVector outnames(nsize + msize);
  out.attr("names") = outnames;
  for(int i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
    out[i] = x[i];
    outnames[i] = xnames[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < msize; i++) {
    out[nsize+i] = y[i];
    outnames[nsize+i] = ynames[i];
  }

  return(out);
}')

x <- as.list(runif(1e6)); names(x) <- sample(letters, 1e6, T)
y <- as.list(runif(1e6)); names(y) <- sample(letters, 1e6, T)

microbenchmark(cLists(x,y), c(x,y), times=3)
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 cLists(x, y) 31.70104 31.86375 32.09983 32.02646 32.29922 32.57198     3  a 
      c(x, y) 47.31037 53.21409 56.41159 59.11781 60.96220 62.80660     3   b
```

Note: by copying to `std::string` you're also losing possible character encoding information, whereas working with just R/Rcpp preserves.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. The output is correct, but unfortunately it is also much less performant than the R version.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
List cLists(List x, List y) {
  int nsize = x.size(); 
  int msize = y.size(); 
  List out(nsize + msize);

  CharacterVector xnames = x.names();
  CharacterVector ynames = y.names();

  for(int i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
    out[i] = x[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < msize; i++) {
    out[nsize+i] = y[i];
  }

  std::vector<std::string> z(x.size() + y.size());
  std::copy(xnames.begin(), xnames.end(), z.begin());
  std::copy(ynames.begin(), ynames.end(), z.begin() + x.size());

  out.attr("names") = z; 

  return(out);
}')
```

Output:

```
cLists(rlist, listadd)
```

> ```
> $a
> [1] "123"
>
> $typ
> [1] "fdb"
> ```